# Issue adding multiple librarys in .pro file - qmake

Tags: qt, qmake

### Context

- Ubuntu 17.0
- Qt4
- QMake version 2.01a
- Using Qt version 4.8.7 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

### Issue

I encouter an issue when i want to add 2 or more librarys to `.pro` file.
Here is the line in the `.pro` that tells to link the librairies :

`LIBS += -L /path/to/folder1 -l1 -L /path/to/folder2 -l2`

During compilation, the libraries' link part of the command line is broken (missing `-L` for `/path/to/folder2`) :

> g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o bin/a.out main.o 
>   -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L /path/to/folder1 -l1 /path/to/folder2 -l2 
>   -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread

I have the same issue doing :

```
LIBS += -L /path/to/folder1 -l1
LIBS += -L /path/to/folder2 -l2
```

I run `qmake` after any change.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not put spaces between `-L` and the path:

```
LIBS += -L/path/to/folder1 -l1 -L/path/to/folder2 -l2
```

Comment: Thank you, you're the best. It's not related to Qt at all ... Maybe close the question or set the duplicate i did not find ...

Comment: @Alrick It is related to qmake. Normally, you can put a space between `-L` and the path. The compiler/linker will accept it just fine. But qmake cannot deal with that space. So it's a qmake thing.